# drush updb fails with "the 'media_delete_action' plugin does not exist" after 8.4.6 > 8.5.1 update

Tags: 8, updating, media

We have recently updated a Drupal `8.4.6` installation via composer to Drupal `8.5.1`. After the composer update I ran

```
drush updb
```

as usual. However, the command fails at one point with the following error message:

```
Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "media_delete_action" plugin does not     [error]
exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of
…\htdocs\casali\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

After that, every `drush updb` wants to do the following updates, since they are never completed:

```
system module :
  Change plugin IDs of actions.
  Clear caches due to schema changes in core.entity.schema.yml.

views module :
  Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
  Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage  to entity_link.
  Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters.
  Fix cache max age for table displays.
  Include views data table provider in views dependencies.
```

I am not quite sure what to do here. As far as I have researched, `media_delete_action` is part of the `media_entity` module. However, that module is already part of the core in Drupal 8.4.x (https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity).

If I run

```
drush en media_entity
```

it tells me

```
media_entity was not found.                                                                                                [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                    [ok]
media_entity
Would you like to download them? (y/n):
```

But I don't think I should have to do that, since it's already part of the core?

Comment: I don't think its called media_entity anymore

Comment: True, it's only called `media`. But that module is already enabled anyway.

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade path mentioned on the project page?

Comment: The upgrade path is only applicable for projects that have been started prior to Drupal 8.4. I am not upgrading from `media_entity` to `media`. The installation always only was on Drupal 8.4 and it always only used `media`.

Comment: I've asked because media_entity_actions is part of the upgraded media in 8.4 which includes the missing plugin https://cgit.drupalcode.org/media_entity_actions/tree/src/Plugin/Action/DeleteMedia.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we were able to solve this problem:

Temporarily install `drupal/media_entity_actions`:

```
composer require drupal/media_entity_actions:^1.0
drush en media_entity_actions
```

Run the database update:

```
drush updb
```

This time it will work:

```
system module :
  Change plugin IDs of actions.
  Clear caches due to schema changes in core.entity.schema.yml.

views module :
  Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
  Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage  to entity_link.
  Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters.
  Fix cache max age for table displays.
  Include views data table provider in views dependencies.

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Post updating system                                                                                                       [ok]
Post updating system                                                                                                       [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Post updating views                                                                                                        [ok]
Cache rebuild complete.                                                                                                    [ok]
Finished performing updates.                                                                                               [ok]
```

Then the module can be uninstalled safely:

```
drush pm-uninstall media_entity_actions
composer remove drupal/media_entity_actions
```

Comment: In this situation, you *might* even need to download the tar.gz from drupal.org and extract it into modules/contrib (e.g. if you find the production server doesn't have sufficient memory or swap to run a composer require or update).