# The pdf_thumbnail plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, updating, plugins

After I tried to update the database I got the following error:

> Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException:
>   [error] The "pdf_thumbnail" plugin does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52
>   of
>   /home/www/sites/stdev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

I tried to find the solution and found one of a similar issue:

[drush updb fails with "the 'media_delete_action' plugin does not exist" after 8.4.6 > 8.5.1 update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259263/drush-updb-fails-with-the-media-delete-action-plugin-does-not-exist-after-8)

Alas, I can't apply that solution because I don't know which module uses the pdf_thumbnail plugin. How can I find it out which module uses the plugin and solve the problem with the update?

Comment: Have you try update entities and db  `drush entity-updates` `drush updb` ?.

Comment: I've just tried but to no avail.

Comment: Did you uninstall any module use this `plugin_id`  `pdf_thumbnail` before.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I get it. I didn't uninstall any module. I did take an existing site and updated it with Composer update --with-dependencies. Then I ran "Drush updb -y" and got that message about the pdf_thumbnail plugin.

Comment: I am also seeing this bug.  Other updates are not being run as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by first re-enabling the PDF module, and then by updating core.

In my composer setup, the PDF module was a git submodule.  However, my shared host would not work with that.  So, I removed the cached information

```
git rm --cached web/modules/contrib/pdf
```

And then I added the code in that directory to my main repo.

Next, enable the PDF module.

Finally, proceed with the update process, and run `update.php` or `drush updb`